# Primitive colliders on complex model in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I just imported my tree model from blender and i want to add colliders to it. It has animation attached to it(tree is breaking and falling). I have read about adding colliders to animated objectsand from what I understood I just have to add many primitive colliders to different bones. My problem is that I can't rotate this primitive colliders and i cant make them fit shape of the object. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an empty gameobject under the bone and add the collider onto that. The colliders rotation follows the rotation of the gameobject it was added to.